# Xcode7 to xcode8 storyboard porting issue

Tags: storyboard, xcode8

I just installed new xcode 8 and it gave me the option to resolve old (xcode7) storyboard to the new format. I did that, and everything looked good.

Then when I launched my app I noticed that some of my UI's are messed up, in particular UIImageViews. In a debugger I did some investigation and found out that those views have no constraints, although in my storyboard I do have them set up.

EDIT: after some more investigation I noticed one thing. I'm checking the properties of my views in viewWillAppear and at that time the view that should be setup from the storyboard have these random values (frame,constraints, etc). When I check these views in the viewDidAppear all the values are correct as they defined int he storyboard.

Here is another post that is related to the issue I'm describing, I think: [When is view frame size set in iOS10 SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39446354/when-is-view-frame-size-set-in-ios10-sdk)

Has anyone experienced a similar issue?

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.